# Solving $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1-x)^{a+1}}e^{\frac{x}{x-1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can anyone please help me to solve the integral ? :
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{a - 1} \over \left(1 - x\right)^{a + 1}}
\,\exp\left(x \over x - 1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

I don't even know how to start. Thanks in advance !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start rewriting the integral in this way:

$$\int_0^1\ \frac{x^a}{x} \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x)^a}\ e^{\frac{x}{x-1}}\ \text{d}y$$

Let's rewrite the integral in this form:

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^a \frac{1}{x(x-1)}e^{\frac{x}{x-1}}\ \text{d}x$$

Now let's perform the substitution:

$$y = \frac{x}{1-x} ~~~~~~~ \text{d}y = -\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{y^2}{x^2}\ \text{d}x ~~~~~ \text{hence} ~~~~~ \text{d}x = \frac{x^2}{y^2}\ \text{d}y$$

In this way the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} y^a\ e^{-y}\left(\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\right)\frac{x^2}{y^2}\ \text{d}y$$

But now we can simplify one $x$ and get

$$\int_0^{+\infty} y^a\ e^{-y}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)}\right)\frac{x}{y^2}\ \text{d}y$$

And now, if you take a look, you'll see that in the integrand you have a term in $x$ which is

$$\frac{x}{1-x} ~~~~~ \text{that is nothing but} ~~~ y$$

So we finally get:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} y^a\ e^{-y}\frac{y}{y^2}\ \text{d}y = \int_0^{+\infty} y^a\ e^{-y}\frac{1}{y}\ \text{d}y  = \int_0^{+\infty} y^{a-1}\ e^{-y}\ \text{d}y$$

This is nothing but the definition of the gamma function:

$$\Gamma(a) = \int_0^{+\infty} y^{a-1}\ e^{-y}\ \text{d}y$$

Which is $(a-1)!$ if and only if $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

So your integral gives you

$$\Gamma(a)$$

Answer (score 3):

By letting $t=x/(1-x)$, we obtain $dt=dx/(x-1)^2$ and
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}}{(1-x)^{a+1}}e^{\frac{x}{x-1}}dx=
\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{a-1}\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{1-x}}\cdot \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2}=
\int_0^{+\infty} t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt=\Gamma(a).$$
For the last step take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Note that the integral is convergent iff $-(a-1)<1$, that is for $a>0$.
Moreover if $a$ is a positive integer then $\Gamma(a)=(a-1)!$.